# In SQL Server, how can I execute a math expression stored in string for an entire column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in an SQL server table that has stored math expressions in string, in the form of "1X1350+3X400". I need to create a new column with the outcome of the calculation, in this case it should be 2,550.

I have been able to get this outcome for single values using sp_executesql, but only for single cells, not for the entire column, which is what I need.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't. SQL, the language, doesn't allow it. You can't do that in any relational database product. You could use dynamic SQL but that's how SQL injection attacks happen. Imagine what would happen if that expression contained `'; drop table users --`

Comment: What is the actual *business* requirement? Where does that expression come from? How often does it change? Why not add a computed column with that expression? Or create a view including that expression?

Comment: The safest way to build an "arbitrary expression evaluator", if you really needed it, is to keep it client-side. If that's not an option, you can move it server-side by using CLR functions. Typically requirements like these smack of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/276538) though, where the proper solution to the real problem is something completely different. (For example, a spreadsheet -- using a spreadsheet as a database is a bad idea, but so is doing the opposite. They can complement each other nicely, though.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: don't say "can't do that in _any_ relational database". This is quite easy to do in at least two: [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=31c9e13cd3d4b95fb55201a519416d8b) and [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4367b9e898949e3993e45f8c0deb1586) - but I do agree with the problems about SQL injection here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your examples prove my point - without dynamic SQL there's no way to `eval` an expression. You could use dynamic SQL in SQL Server as well, `exec 'select ' + table.expression`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there are ways to execute scripts in many databases, but I doubt what the OP is asking for here. Eg SQL Server's `sp_execute_external_script` can be used to execute Python, R, Java and "C#" scripts (the C# quasi-support looks like something to silence complaints). That's not the same as evaluating expressions at runtime though, and can be quite slow if used carelessly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: you can actually do it in plain SQL in Postgres as there are functions built-in to do something like that. See e.g. here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=877d9ce1545577d195b74bff2faa2882 - a similar approach is possible in Oracle as well. And that's even safe for SQL injection as it will simply result in an error if you include e.g. DDL or DML in there.

Comment: If your expressions could be well defined, you could store them in a table and simply calculate them. Eg four columns `A` `B` `C` `D` then do `A * B + C * D`

Comment: @Charlieface yes I think that's worth trying. Is there a way I can store each of the numbers in the string in a column and then I will find the best way to calculate them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will check the code in dbfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, just make four columns, then you can do the calculation off them

Comment: @Charlieface sorry if I was not clear. I meant if there is a way to isolate only the numbers in the string in question, and storing each number to a different column.